# Is it possible to use 'join' in INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I am trying to alter my code so when there is no row with a matching `ean13` in `webshop_stock` it needs to `INSERT` a new row.

MYSQL is currently not accepting my code. i have tried a few things in order to get it working. My search on the worldwide-web did not find a good example with `INSERT INTO - JOIN - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. So my question is, is it possible?

The problem at this moment is that my rows get created when they not exist, but the rows that exist does not get updated.

**Tested the following code:**

```
INSERT INTO webshop_stock 
   (id_warehouse,id_product,id_product_attribute,ean13, physical_quantity, usable_quantity)
   SELECT
        '1',
        pa.id_product,
        pa.id_product_attribute,
        pa.ean13, 
        ai.quantity,
        ai.quantity
    FROM
        webshop_product_attribute pa, 
        Adcount_input ai 
    WHERE 
        pa.ean13 = ai.ean13 
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT id_product_attribute FROM webshop_stock
        WHERE id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        physical_quantity = ai.quantity,
        usable_quantity = ai.quantity
```

**Original code:**

```
UPDATE
    webshop_stock AS s
JOIN(
    SELECT 
        pa.ean13, 
        pa.id_product_attribute,
        pa.id_product,
        ai.quantity 
    FROM 
        webshop_product_attribute pa, 
        Adcount_input ai 
    WHERE 
        pa.ean13=ai.ean13) q
SET
        s.id_warehouse = 1,
        s.id_product = q.id_product,
        s.id_product_attribute = q.id_product_attribute,
        s.ean13 = q.ean13,
        s.physical_quantity = q.quantity,
        s.usable_quantity = q.quantity 
WHERE 
        s.id_product_attribute = q.id_product_attribute
```

Comment: `But mysql is not accepting my tested code` - does it error out or does it simply not do what you expect it to? Please be descriptive when reporting errors, "not working" is not how we tell each other what went wrong.

Comment: Currently it gives no error, with the code provided below. it insert when row does not exist but does not update if row exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED** this code does what i need.

```
INSERT INTO webshop_stock 
   (id_warehouse, id_product, id_product_attribute, ean13, physical_quantity, usable_quantity)
   SELECT
        '1',
        pa.id_product,
        pa.id_product_attribute,
        pa.ean13, 
        ai.quantity,
        ai.quantity
    FROM
        webshop_product_attribute pa, 
        Adcount_input ai 
    WHERE 
        pa.ean13 = ai.ean13
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        physical_quantity = ai.quantity, usable_quantity = ai.quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
INSERT <table> <field list>
SELECT ... JOIN ...
```

There is **NO** `INSERT JOIN SELECT` in mysql. It's `INSERT SELECT JOIN`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: you need a `select`. a plain insert has **NO** join capabilities `insert ... select ... join` works. `insert ... join` is illegal syntax.